# Average multiple scores of the same topic

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

Say I have a spreadsheet that contains quizzes taken by students and their scores.

I want to create another table of that data the gives me an average of 2 quizzes that are related to the same topic. I have attached an example. Not all topics contain two different quizzes, some just consist of one single quiz.

Maybe someone could help me solve this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qQOW.png)

I tried to use a pivot table but it creates a column for each test, not exactly what I need.

Comment: So have you tried AVERAGEIFS() ?

Comment: @SolarMike I couldn't find an example of a similar use of AVERAGEIFS()

Comment: Well, the answer shown does a good job, it’s also in the excel help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use AverageIFS() like this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,F$1,$A:$A,$E2)
```

As per the screenshot below. Hope this helps!!!

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly!